# Which one is a more reliable matching scheme, EREGI or STRIPOS?

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

Which scheme according to you is a better one in case of matching?

Is it eregi or stripos or any other method?

Comment: If you just need to do a simple substring match, then stripos or strpos are probably best. If you need to match on something more complicated, like matching a pattern of characters, then regular expressions could be the better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends if you want to do exact match or [regexp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) match.

- [**stripos**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) is for case insensitive matching of string in another string
- [**eregi**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is case insensitive [regexp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) matching in a string
- [**fnmatch**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) is the third alternative. It's simple [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Computing) matching as in [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing).

Moreover, **eregi** is deprecated, is not binary safe and does not work well with UTF-8.
For regexp matching you should use [**preg_match**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with **`i`** flag instead.

Comment: which one is prefferable in which situation??

Comment: If you just need to do a simple substring match, then stripos or strpos are probably best.

If you need to match on something more complicated, like matching a pattern of characters, then regular expressions could be the better choice.

Comment: @SilentGhost: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.regex.php "Note: As of PHP 5.3.0 this extension is deprecated, calling any function provided by this extension will issue an E_DEPRECATED notice"

Comment: yeah, but soon. the problem with ereg is that it doesn't work well with UTF8